# ASP.NET MVC - Routing Engine Appending Unexpected Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a pair of routes that both point to the same action and depending on the supplied route data I would like one route to be chosen over the other. Trouble is, the routing engine seems to be automatically appending route values that I am explicitly telling it not to.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Products_Search_Paged",
 "products/search/page{pageNbr}",
 new { controller = "Products", action = "Search" },
 new { pageNbr = @"\d+" },
 new[] { "Web.Components.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "Products_Search",
 "products/search",
 new { controller = "Products", action = "Search" },
 new[] { "Web.Components.Controllers" }
);
```

Note, the only difference between the two routes is the addition of */page{pageNbr}* in *Products_Search_Paged*.

The problem I am experiencing is that when I am viewing the route *Products_Search_Paged* at */products/search/page2?name=foo*, for example, and I want to create a link to */products/search*, if I call `Url.Action("Search, "Products", new { pageNbr = "" })` it is ignoring my declaration `pageNbr = ""` and creating the link */products/search?pageNbr=2*. Alternatively, if I create a link with `Url.Action("Search", "Products", new { pageNbr = 5 })` I end up with */products/search/page5*, as expected.

I've tried reorganizing the routes and placing *Products_Search* before *Products_Search_Paged* which seems to eliminate the problem with ?pageNbr=# being appended despite nulling it, but that had the added effect of it not formatting the *Products_Search_Paged* as */page3* and rather producing */products/search?pageNbr=3*.

From the testing I've performed thus far, I cannot find any reason why the *pageNbr* route value is getting appended as its current value even when I explicitly set it to something else in a provided RouteValueDictionary.

The two solutions to this problem that come to mind currently are either to use `Url.RouteLink()` to explicitly define which route I want to use, or to manually remove the *pageNbr* key from the RouteData.DataTokens prior to generating the URL. Before I choose one of those solutions though, I was hoping somebody might be able to identify why my current, seemingly legitimate approach, is not producing the results expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the declarations, add a default value of pageNbr to the pageless URL, and then invoke it with a pageNbr of 1. That also has the advantage that links wit pagenbr of 1 will be the simpler link.

Comment: This seems to work, but if I'm understanding you correctly I must always call pageNbr=1 to get the pageless route?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to pass pageNbr=1 all the time, in case you're on a URL that already has pageNbr in it.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable. Thanks Brad

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be your regex constraining the value of `pageNbr`- empty string does not match `\d+`.  You have explicitly put it into the routing dictionary, so the route that uses it is the best match...

I haven't tested alternatives (currently away from my windows box), but giving it a default value of `UrlParameter.Optional` may help.  You could also try changing the regex to `\d*`.

Comment: This was actually brought to my attention by someone else and I've tried both of these approaches but it doesn't really solve the problem because {pageNbr} is not an optional parameter. If the user tries to visit */products/search/page* it shouldn't work at all.